# Azure DevOps AWS Serverless application deployment - S3 bucket per environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-devops, aws-cloudformation, continuous-deployment

I have followed [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-lambda-deployment-task-enhancements-in-the-aws-tools-for-vsts/) on how to separately package and deploy a .NET Core serverless application on AWS.

I'm trying to deploy to different environments, which I can achieve by parameterising the `CloudFormation` template and creating different stages in the Azure DevOps release pipeline, each stage passing different parameters to the template. However, there is one aspect that's confusing me a little bit. From the guide, an `AWS Lambda .NET Core Deployment` task is added to create a deployment package in the CI part. In that task, a S3 bucket name is specified, which is where the compiled code will be uploaded to. However, this means that one single S3 bucket will contain uploaded code for **all** environments. What if I wanted to upload the code to a different S3 bucket, depending on the environment being deployed to? Or is it normal practice to have just one S3 bucket in this scenario?

I thought of creating the bucket at the release pipeline stages, but the task to package the serverless application (during CI) **requires** a bucket name to be supplied.

Am I going the wrong way about this?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm facing the same issue. I worked around it by cloning the same step to publish to S3, and having one referencing a Dev bucket, one a Prod bucket and so on. But it feels 'off'.